# php7 with mongodb how to update to key (contains dot)

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm using php7.x and Mongodb 3.6.5. and i want to add to My IP in mongodb as json key.

```
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite(['ordered' => false]);
$bulk->update(
    ['m_model' => $_POST['mid']],
    ['$set' => ['statistics.play.' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] => 
    ['time'=>$connectionTime]]],
    ['multi' => false, 'upsert' => false]
);
$conn -> executeBulkWrite('db.tempName', $bulk);
```

I'm using following code, it will be make some json file.

[image]
but i don't want this data structure.

[image: asdf]
I want like this.

In addtion, i don't want replace dot to any words or hash(md5 etc..) too.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly you can't do this, since `The field names cannot contain the dot (.) character.` ([See here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/)).
Since you don't want to replace dots by accepted character, the only way to achieve this is to update your scheme for something like this :

```
{
  statistics:
    {
      ...,
      play:[{ip:"1.1.1.1",time:"asdf"}]   // <== Note the array
    }
}
```

In addition, it can be easier in future to query play.time (time in any of array entry) than play.1_1_1_1.time, play.1_1_1_2.time, etc...

Comment: Oops... so sad it... then, only can json key contain the dot by hand?

Comment: only value of field can contain dot (here value of field play.0.ip), not the field name itself.

Comment: Thanks. i solved this prolbem just replace dot to hyphen. :'(